# "The request URI is invalid" error when trying to upload a file into ADLS2 from .net core API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to write an api for uploading a file into  my ADLS2 storage.

Below the code snippet

```
    var credential = new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential();
    var fileSystemClient = new DataLakeFileSystemClient(new Uri("https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net"), credential);//_applicationSettings?.ObjectStoreSettings?.Uri
    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = fileSystemClient.GetFileClient($@"general\landing\{objectPushRequest.File.Name}");
    using (Stream fileStream = objectPushRequest.File.OpenReadStream())
    {
        // Upload the file asynchronously
        await fileClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
        message = BuildMessage(Status.Success, ErrorCodes.NoError, "Object Push service uploaded file to Blob");
        return (message, null);
    }
```

But when I execute the above code, I am getting invalid uri error

> Azure.RequestFailedException: The request URI is invalid.
> RequestId:a2504662-501f-0060-0145-6ccc0c000000
> Time:2023-04-11T07:17:10.8515000Z Status: 400 (The request URI is
> invalid.) ErrorCode: InvalidUri
>
> Content: {"error":{"code":"InvalidUri","message":"The request URI is
> invalid.\nRequestId:a2504662-501f-0060-0145-6ccc0c000000\nTime:2023-04-11T07:17:10.8515000Z"}}

But the above dfs url I copied from Azure portal itself.

So I didnt understand what I did wrong! Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample code snippet and the error message its pretty clear that the failure is due to `Invalid Request URL`.

You can leverage the below sample code to upload file to ADLS Gen 2 Storage:

```
public async Task UploadFile(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient)
{
    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
        fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");

    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync("uploaded-file.txt");

    FileStream fileStream =
        File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\contoso\\Temp\\file-to-upload.txt");

    long fileSize = fileStream.Length;

    await fileClient.AppendAsync(fileStream, offset: 0);

    await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: fileSize);

}
```

More Info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet). Hope this helps.